# How to implement filter by using an endpoint in nodeJs and Express?

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am building a small app and I am stuck with my backend.I am getting all the the books when testing the endpoint and also one book.When trying to implement filter by category,price and name is giving me all books, can anybody tells me what I am doing wrong? thanks a lot. I have also created a database with mysql workbench, all data come from there.Here are my codes bellow:

```
//Get all books
app.get("/api/books", (req, res) => {
  let mysql = "SELECT * FROM books";
  let query = conn.query(mysql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 200, error: null, response: results }));
  });
});

//Get single product
app.get("/api/books/:id", (req, res) => {
  let mysql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id=" + req.params.id;
  let query = conn.query(mysql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 200, error: null, response: results }));
  });
});


 I am getting same result with these two url:(http://localhost:3000/books?category=stories and http://localhost:3000/books)

app.get("api/books", (req, res) => {
  const category = req.query.category;
  const categoryBooks = Books.filter((cat) => cat.category === category);
  res.send(categoryBooks);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this into code and I also provide URL endpoint so copy-paste into the browser.
// URL endpoint example : http://localhost:3000/api/books/filter?category=store

```
// URL endpoint example : http://localhost:3000/api/books/filter?category=store
app.get("/api/books/filter", (req, res) => {
    const category = req.query.category;
    console.log("category is : ",category)

    // const categoryBooks = Books.filter((cat) => cat.category === category);
    let mysql = "SELECT * FROM books ;" 
    let query = conn.query(mysql, (err, results) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      const categoryBasedBooks = results.filter((book)=>book.category===category)
      console.log("categoryBasedBooks :", categoryBasedBooks )

      res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 200, error: null, response: results }));
    });

});

// URL endpoint example : http://localhost:3000/api/books/nofilter?category=store
app.get("/api/books/nofilter", (req, res) => {
  const category = req.query.category;
  console.log("category is : ",category)

  // You can get same results without using filter by using SQL query WHERE clause
  let mysql = `SELECT * FROM books WHERE category='${category}' ;`
  let query = conn.query(mysql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("categoryBasedBooks :", results )
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 200, error: null, response: results }));
  });
  
});
```

Comment: Hi Ajith-stark, thanks for your help I gonna try it out and let know

Comment: Hi again Ajith-stark, I have just updated my post if you can check again and give me suggestion. I try also according your last post but it did not work. my data type looks something like this: "books": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "mogly",
      "price": "400",
      "category": "history",
    },

Comment: its because You have 2 route with same URLs  `app.get("/api/books",...)`.
Nodejs runs line by line.
 when you hit GET `/api/books`  nodejs will execute the fist occurrence of that which in your case 1st block of code in above .
so change that URL or http method.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have changed it from url:(http://localhost:3000/books?category=stories to url:(http://localhost:3000/books/filter?category=stories still not work

Comment: I hope you haven't forgotten to consider `/api` in URL.
i Have changed the answer so copy-paste into your code, It should work as expected